# Creating a dimension in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table witch doesn't have its dimension table, for example, in the table below I have only descriptive items (Function), but not the key of the dimension table:

```
Id  Employee  Function
1   Chris     Bartender
2   Millena   Waiter
3   Jessica   Firefighter
4   Paul      Waiter
```

I don't have my DIM_Function, in other words, I wanted to create a dimension table having those values, and as the table grows up and new records are populated in my table, the another DIM_Function must have these values. I already heard about surrogate key, but don't know how to use it.

In the end, creating a fact table, the column 'Function' must store the ID that I created to the DIM_Funcion.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not at all understand what are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I don't have a dimension table, so I'd like to create one

Comment: So what is preventing you?

Comment: Note that while it's common practice to use a surrogate key for your dimensions, it's not inherent in the dimensional model.  You can use the existing Function name as the key of the dimension.  The main role of the dimension table is to have a single place to store all the other attributes of the Function.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of this is that you would create a dimension table of unique values with IDs (the ID column would be a primary key and an identity column), and then update your fact table with that ID. Then whenever you load more data into the fact table, you first try to retrieve the ID for each record from the dimension table. If it isn't found, you would insert a new record for it, and then retrieve the new ID. One way to do this is via a stored procedure - with the raw data having been written to a staging table - and would look something like this (using your example of 'Function'):

```
UPDATE Staging
SET S.FunctionID = D.FunctionID
FROM
    Staging S
    JOIN Dim_Function D ON S.[Function] = D.[Function]

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Staging WHERE FunctionID IS NULL)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Dim_Function ([Function])

    SELECT DISTINCT [Function]
    FROM Staging
    WHERE FunctionID IS NULL
    ;

    UPDATE Staging
    SET S.FunctionID = D.FunctionID
    FROM
        Staging S
        JOIN Dim_Function D ON S.[Function]= D.[Function]
    WHERE S.FunctionID IS NULL

END
```

You can then insert the 'FunctionID' rather than the actual 'Function' value into the fact table (from the staging table).